# c# Generic method with async delegate

Tags: c#, generics

I have created this generic method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Executes a list of items
/// </summary>
/// <param name="procedureName">The name of the procedure</param>
/// <param name="parameters">List of oracle parameters</param>
/// <param name="limit">The limit of the results to return</param>
/// <param name="mapper">The oracle mapper method</param>
/// <returns></returns>
protected async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ListAsync<T>(string procedureName, IList<OracleParameter> parameters, int limit, Func<IDataReader, T> mapper)
{
    // Create our list
    var models = new List<T>();
    var counter = 0;

    // Get our reader and return our model
    using (var reader = await _oracleUnitOfWork.ExecuteReaderAsync(procedureName, parameters))
    {
        // While we have rows and our counter 
        while (reader.Read() && ((counter < limit || limit == 0) || limit == 0))
        {
            // If we have a limit, increase our counter (this is first to stop 0 based index messing the amount of objects to return)
            if (limit > 0)
                counter++;

            // Get our item from the database
            models.Add(mapper(reader));
        }
    }

    // Return our list
    return models;
}
```

Which I can invoke like this:

```
return await ListAsync("IBPA_MANFCOMPLAINT.complaintSearch", parameters, yield, OracleMapper.Complaint.Map);
```

But I want to extend this a little.
The Mapper just uses the **IDataReader** to assign the column values to the model properties.
For stock instead of using this:

```
return await ListAsync("ibpa_stock.readRelatedLotstoLot", parameters, 0, OracleMapper.Stock.Map);
```

I want to do a get request, a bit like this:

```
return await ListAsync("ibpa_stock.readRelatedLotstoLot", parameters, 0, async (reader) => await GetAsync(reader["lotno"].ToString()));
```

What can I do to keep things DRY, but at the same time to allow that invocation?

Comment: Is the problem that you sometimes have an `async` method and sometimes not? And the type `Func<IDataReader, T>` can't accomodate both?

Comment: Note that I'd strongly suggest you not have a method like this in the first place.  Rather than having a single method that executes a procedure, takes the first N values of the result, and then maps each value to something else, taking in all of the information to do all of those things, you should instead have a method that gets the results of a procedure.  If someone wants the first N items, they can call a method to take the first N items (`Take`).  If they want to map the items into something else, they can call a method to do that (`Select`).  You're not getting anything out doing this.

Comment: Yeah I know this :D but unfortunately I have no control over the sprocs

Comment: @r3plica You don't need to change anything about the stored procedures to make such a change, you just need to remove this unhelpful method and call the method that does each thing that you want when you want to do a thing, rather than trying to do them all at once, given that doing so doesn't get you anything, and has its costs.

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have two overloads of the method, one that accepts a `Func<IDataReader, T>`, and one that accepts a `Func<IDataReader, Task<T>>`.  The second one will need to `await` the method call when it invokes it, the former won't.

Comment: That sounds fine, but won't there be a lot of repeated code?

Comment: @r3plica There's only a handful of code in the whole method, even as it sits, half of which doesn't need to be there at all, so no, not really.